# How can I get index’s value?

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote codes,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\s|,', engine='python')
df =df.pivot_table(index=['DATE','NAME'])
```

df shows

```
                           A        B        C
DATE    　　   NAME
2017-01-01    Tom          40    56    75      
              John         60    70    86           
              Juddy        44    90    60           
2017-01-02    Tom          30    60    70     
              John         20    50    80           
              Juddy        40    40    50      
・
・
・
```

I want to get this NAME index’s list.
When I wrote  df.index　,all index can be gotten.
I also write

```
df.loc["NAME"]
```

or

```
df.ix["NAME"]
```

but my ideal output cannot be gotten.

I want to get all index’s list like
["Tom","John","Juddy"・・・]
, so how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
```

Comment: You can also specify by index label, e.g. `df.index.get_level_values("NAME")`.

Answer (score 1):

Might be slightly cleaner to call by column name

```
df.index.get_level_values('NAME').tolist()
```